# How to save more power on top of Powertop and TLP?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, eclipse, powertop

I have TLP and Powertop to run at boot (with autotune for powertop set at boot as well). However, I still get abysmal battery life -- 2 hours usually at max when I'm using Eclipse or the internet -- and I can't find any specific ways to save more power and get more life. I'm going to need my laptop for school soon and 4 hours would really be preferrable. I've already rfkill block'd my bluetooth; is there anything else I can do? I'm pretty sure my battery itself isn't the issue either as it's fine on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps letting us know details like your TLP config and state, release, desktop, battery, specs...I've also read in the TLP faq that it doesn't get along with Powertop. http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#powertop

Comment: Having TLP *and* powertop tweak your powersaving at the same time is nonsense.  I suspect your problem is named "hybrid graphics". See http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#nvidia